PWA Standalone audio controls and background play
I'm making a PWA web player and stucked in this situation.
When pwa is installed as minimal-ui, audio controls still working when app is in background or lock screen, but when is standalone mode, this controls doesn't work anymore and the audio stops to playing until user go back to the app. Anyone has this issue before and can help me?
Here is an video example what I'm talking about.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFt-P6M6ANg

I resolved this issue by playing a silent MP3 in the background to prevent the PWA from being killed by the system. You can try this approach to keep your PWA active in the background.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
